# Adding active class for two anchor tags

Tags: javascript

I have the following markup

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit Profile <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Account Settings<span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
</div>
```

And this is javascript I applied

```
var sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

for (var i = 0; i <= sidebar.length; i++) {
  sidebar.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  });
}
```

and I want to like this following screenshot

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: And what is the problem you're experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.querySelectorAll` if you want a *collection* of elements. `.querySelector` only returns the first matching element. Also make sure to test `i < sidebars.length` rather than `i <= sidebars.length`.

```
var as = document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar > a");
for(let i = 0; i < as.length; i++){
  as[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.classList.toggle('active');
  })
}
```

Even better, iterate over the as directly, avoiding `for` loops (and off-by-one errors) entirely:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar > a").forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener("click", () => {
      a.classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

(older browsers don't support NodeList.forEach though, so if you use this method, make sure to polyfill too)

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the `<=` => `<` change you made as well. And the `sidebar[i]` bit. (Otherwise, it's a bit of a game of spot-the-difference.)

Comment: Thanks ! but i want to add active class on `a` tag, but this code add active class only sidebar class.......

Comment: Edited - just change to `document.querySelectorAll(".sidebar > a");` to select the `a`s inside of `.sidebar`