# Active class navigation sidebar with anchors

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, sidebar

I have a navigation sidebar with several anchors in an xsl document. Based on [Adding active class for two anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507045/adding-active-class-for-two-anchor-tags) suggestions, I have tried to apply the same script, but I don't see why there is no modification of the style according to CSS.

```
<script>
     <![CDATA[
       document.querySelectorAll("#menu-hermeneutics li > a").forEach(a => {
          a.addEventListener("click", () => {
              a.addClass('active'); 
          });
       });]]>
</script>
```

```
<ul id="menu-hermeneutics">
    <li><a href="#general-overview">General Overview</a></li>
    <li><a href="#context-overview">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#result-overview">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#clanA">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#aff-clanA">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#clanB">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#aff-clanB">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#DR">...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#clanUNK">...</a></li>                
</ul>
```

And CSS:

```
#menu-hermeneutics > .active {background-color: grey; color: white; font-weight: 700; margin-right: 100px; width: 200px; }
```

In advance, thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code at `document.querySelectorAll("#menu-hermeneutics li > a")` means it's gonna query all `a` tag and add class `active` if clicked on it, but your css below, it's different. `#menu-hermeneutics > .active` means it will select `#menu-hermeneutics`'s children (here is `li`, not `a`) with class `active` because you are using `>`. If you want to css at all children `a` only, you can do this `#menu-hermeneutics a.active`
You can take a look at [here](https://codepen.io/aladida95/pen/XWXNPzL?editors=1111) for more details. Hope it would help

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. As for a.active, in your example, .active effect is always active once I click on the link while I need it to be removed when I click on another link. Anyway, when I copy/paste your suggested script to my xsl file, there is no modification style at all while it's working on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncoxdgqa/1/).

Comment: When I look to my browser online tool, it says also there is the following mistake: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'." But I doubt the mistake comes from here...

Comment: Now it works! It was a problem with `>` becoming `&gt` automatically in the script of xsl file. To avoid this problem, I had to save the script in .js file. So thank you very much @thienhuynh. My other problem is on the .active which needs to be removed once the user click on another link of this current sidebar menu--apologize for the lack of precision in the content of my initial question.

Comment: Your welcome. The idea for your new problem is you just need to create a function which got same idea when you bind click event to each a, except the processing function is different, removes all the class active before you add .active into clicked element. You can use document.querySelectorAll("#menu-hermeneutics a.active") and remove all class .active in it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions of @ThienHuynh and a colleague, this is the correct code:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("#menu-hermeneutics li a");
  for (const link of links) {
    link.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    var target = e.target;

    links.forEach(function(currentLink) {
        currentLink.classList.remove('active');
    });

      // if target already had .active. remove it. Otherwise, add it
      target.classList.toggle('active');
    })
    }
```

Note: see my comment below regarding `>` vs `&gt` --it was the main problem to avoid a bug.